AttributeError: module 'autokeras' has no attribute 'StructuredDataClassifier'
I'm trying to get Autokeras work on categorial data classification task on Google Colab
import autokeras as ak
clf = ak.StructuredDataClassifier(max_trials=10)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5)
    
loss, accuracy = clf.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print(f"Test Accuracy: {accuracy}")

but the module 'autokeras' has no attribute 'StructuredDataClassifier' keeps appearing. The attribute is no longer within the module so anyone with any workaround?
Autokeras 2.0.0
Python 3.10.12
Thanks
